# Separar cadenas en SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013

tengo una problematica y espero me puedan ayudar.

Mi problema es que tengo que incluir en una view de SQL (que despues mandare a llamar en visual studio 2013) los campos "ciudad" y "estado" pero en la tabla fuente los datos viene en la misma columna y abreviada. Asi que requiero no solo separar la cadena, tambien poner el estado en otra columna y mostrar el estado no abreviado, es decir, poner "ciudad" en una columna y "estado" en otra.

Por ejemplo tengo en mi tabla actual:

```
CIUDAD

'MONTERREY NL' 

'DISTRITO FEDERAL DF'

'SAN NICOLAS GARZA GARCIA NL'
```

Y yo necesito:

```
CIUDAD|ESTADO

'MONTERREY'|'NUEVO LEON'

'DISTRITO FEDERAL'|'DISTRITO FEDERAL'

'SAN NICOLAS GARZA GARCIA'|'NUEVO LEON'
```

Ya intente con un substring y charindex y nada. Lo que me ha causado mas conflicto es que la longitud de las ciudades y estados es variable por lo cual no puedo extraer un determinado numero de caracteres y tampoco tienen un delimitante como coma, punto o algo similar en lo que me pueda basar para extraer y validar el estado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Porque queres solucionar un problema de la vista (porque lo vas a arreglar cuando lo muestres) desde SQL? mas alla de eso, si tenes un separador, y es el ultimo espacio en blanco. Y mas alla de todo eso, deberias tener una tabla de abreviaturas y nombres para extender el nombre

Comment: Ese es el detalle cuando aplico el substring o charindex con el ultimo espacio me sale a medias o cortado, vaya no me lo muestra como yo lo necesito. Es por eso que pregunte porque ya le busque y rebusque y no resulta.

Comment: @GloriaLópez Deberías agregar el código de las pruebas que hiciste y no funcionaron... Tal vez tengas un error, si muestras el código alguien lo puede encontrar.

Comment: Es que lamentablemente es un problema que no tiene solución, a menos que puedas modificar el caracter separador, el espacio es muy ambiguo, ya que tiene estados con una sola palabra y otros con dos (no sé si más). Lo único que se me ocurre es si pudieras recuperar una lista completa de los estados y con algún JOIN identificar la parte "estado"  de la columna.

Comment: La BD es de un tercero y no la puedo modificar, por eso se va a trabajar con una vista para no tocar para nada la tabla.Lo que estoy haciendo es crear una tabla con dos columnas, "AbrEdo" que guarda el nombre abreviado y "NomEdo" con el nombre completo para poder aplicar un where que lo valide. Eso implicaria que solo tengo que separar la cadena desde el primer espacio de derecha a izquierda y aplicar una subconsulta que busque el nombre completo a dicha tabla. Me podrian ayudar a separar esa cadena?

Comment: Gloria, hace eso en la vista, no en el query a la base de datos!! es mucho mas facil trabajar los datos una vez que los tenes.. y tenes muchas mas funciones de manejo de base de datos.. y si la base de datos fuera mia, y vas a ejecutar un query para parsear un string de mi lado, por un problema de tu vista, te diria que no...

Comment: Por eso estoy buscando hasta el cansancio una alternativa para hacerlo porque lo requiero para generar reportes. La vista no tiene ningun problema, solo es necesario agregar el campo estado y asi poder separar la informacion para generar dichos reportes.

Answer (score 1):

No tenemos a mano la función LastCharIndex() que hubiese sido propicio para obtener el último caracter de espacio en blanco de la cadena, sin embargo si que es posible recuperar la cadena en un orden inverso y tomar el índice de posición del primer caracter de espacio en blanco y ocuparlo como argumento de la función RIGHT(), por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @Ciudades table (Ciudad varchar(300));
INSERT INTO @Ciudades VALUES
('MONTERREY NL'), ('DISTRITO FEDERAL DF'), ('SAN NICOLAS GARZA GARCIA NL');

SELECT LEFT(c.Ciudad, LEN(c.Ciudad) - LEN(e.Codigo) - 1) AS Ciudad, e.Estado
FROM 
    @Ciudades c
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT RIGHT(c.Ciudad, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(c.Ciudad)) - 1)) t(Estado)
    INNER JOIN (
       VALUES ('NL', 'NUEVO LEON'), ('DF', 'DISTRITO FEDERAL')
       ) e (Codigo, Estado) ON t.Estado = e.Codigo
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función para obtener el valor que necesitas de la cadena, algo como esto:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ObtenerEdo(@Cadena VARCHAR(100)) 
    RETURNS  VARCHAR(10)
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @Valor      VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @Tabla      TABLE (Num INT IDENTITY(1,1), Valor VARCHAR(10))
    DECLARE @Edo        VARCHAR(10)

    WHILE LEN(@Cadena) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF CHARINDEX(' ',@Cadena) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Valor  = LEFT(@Cadena,CHARINDEX(' ',@Cadena)-1)
            SET @Cadena = RIGHT(@Cadena,LEN(@Cadena) - CHARINDEX(' ',@Cadena))

            INSERT INTO @Tabla (Valor)
            SELECT @Valor
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @Valor  = @Cadena
            SET @Cadena = ''

            INSERT INTO @Tabla (Valor)
            SELECT @Valor
       END
    END

    SELECT  @Edo  = Valor FROM @Tabla   WHERE  Num  =   (SELECT MAX(Num) FROM @Tabla)

    RETURN  @Edo
    END
```

y despues usarlo en tu query para remplazar el estado con vacio, seria algo asi:

```
    SELECT REPLACE(Ciudad, dbo.ObtenerEdo(Ciudad), ''), dbo.ObtenerEdo(Ciudad) FROM TABLA
```

Así obtienes ambos campos, ya solo necesitarías un join para obtener el valor del estado de tu tabla.

Espero te sirva.
Saludos.